# How to group a column of data based on rows

Tags: excel-2010

I have ~10000 rows in a spreadsheet and the first column (A) has a certain ID that I would like to group by.  As an example, A2:A20 has the same ID, then A21:A31 has a different ID, A32:A55 has a different ID and so on, down to the bottom row.

I've tried using the Group button in Excel but I can't seem to get what I need.  I'm looking to make separate row groups for the column ranges I specified above all the way to the bottom of the spreadsheet.  Since I have ~10000 rows, I was looking for a way to not do the grouping manually.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using SUBTOTAL option. Using this the data is automatically grouped with subtotal options.